# Sum one column values if other columns are matched

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark dataframe like this:

```
word1  word2  co-occur
----   -----  ------- 
 w1     w2      10
 w2     w1      15
 w2     w3      11
```

And my expected result is:

```
word1  word2  co-occur
----   -----  ------- 
 w1     w2      25
 w2     w3      11
```

I tried dataframe's `groupBy` and aggregate functions but I couldn't come up with the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a single column containing both words in sorted order, this column can then be used for the `groupBy`. You can create a new column with an array containing `word1` and `word` as follows:

```scala
df.withColumn("words", sort_array(array($"word1", $"word2")))
  .groupBy("words")
  .agg(sum($"co-occur").as("co-occur"))
```

This would produce the following results:

```
 words        co-occur
-----        --------
["w1","w2"]     25
["w2","w3"]     11
```

---

If you would like to have both words as spearate dataframe columns, use the `getItem` method afterwards. For the above example, add the following lines to the above:

```
df.withColumn("word1", $"words".getItem(0))
  .withColumn("word2", $"words".getItem(1))
  .drop($"words")
```

The final resultant dataFrame would look like this:

```
 word1  word2  co-occur
----   -----  ------- 
 w1     w2      25
 w2     w3      11
```